# What is the reason this while loop does not generate output?

Tags: python, function, input, while-loop

I am new to python and trying to learn by doing small projects.

## The problem

Strontium-90, a radioactive element that is part of the fallout
from nuclear explosions, has a half-life of 28 years. This means that a given quantity
of strontium-90 will emit radioactive particles and decay to one-half its size every
28 years. How many years are required for 100 grams of strontium-90 to decay to less
than 1 gram?

My Input code:

```
full_life = int(100)
while full_life < int(1):
      full_life -= 0.5*full_life
      year +=28
      print("The decay time is:",year)
```

On running the above, no output is generated. why is this the case? what am i missing?

Comment: Why use `int()`? Maybe `while full_life > 1:`.

Comment: Why `full_life -= 0.5*full_life` instead of `full_life *= 0.5` or `full_life /= 2`?

Comment: Because `100 < 1` is false, you never enter the loop.

Answer (score 4):

while loop logic is reversed should be:

`while full_life > int(1):`

Comment: Thank you. It does work with the solution you provided. Is it possible to explain the logic behind this? shouldnt it be <= with the logic that the starting cant be greater than 1. 1 represent full life

Comment: No, both 100 and 1 refer to how many *grams* of strontium you have. You want to the loop to run while `full_life` (which *starts* equal to 100) is greater than 1.

Comment: If Python had an `until` loop, then `<` would be appropriate. (Where the hypothetical  `until full_life < 1` is equivalent to `while not (full_life < 1)`, which is equivalent to `while full_life >= 1` (which is technically what the problem as state calls for, not `>`)).

Comment: Each time I run it the amount is increasing for some reason:  The decay time is: 616
The decay time is: 644
The decay time is: 672
The decay time is: 700
The decay time is: 728
The decay time is: 756
The decay time is: 784

Comment: Because you are calling `print` *in* the loop, not *after* the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Right away you have made full_life  100, checking the condition in the while loop comes out as false right away (since 100 < 1 is false).  Since it is false you will not go through the loop.  I imagine what you're looking for is to switch the sign from < to >

```
full_life = int(100)
while full_life < int(1):
    do stuff
```

to

```
full_life = int(100)
while full_life > int(1):
    do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

After you reverse your while loop logic like this:

```
while full_life>1:
   do something
```

The other problem will occur.
You didn't define 'year'
you shuld do this:

```
year=0
```

Comment: That's *a* problem, but not the only one, and not the one that solves the problem currently under investigation.

Answer (score 0):

`full_life` represents the amount of strontium you have. Initially, you have 100 grams, and are starting at year 0.

```
year = 0
full_life = 100
```

You want to decrease `full_life` until it is *less* than 1 gram, which means you execute the body of the loop as long as `full_life` is *greater than or equal* to 1.

```
while full_life >= 1:
    full_life /= 2
    year +=28
print("The decay time is:",year)
```

Each time the condition is true, you divide `full_life` in half, and increment `year` by 28 years. Once the loop has completed, you can output the total number of years before the condition because false.

---

Note this is not entirely correct, as the mass doesn't stay constant for 28 years, then immediately drop by a factor of 2. This is most obvious if you start with 1 gram of strontium. It doesn't take 28 years for *any* of it to decay.

What you really need to do is pick a granularity (hour, day, month, whatever), and figure out from the half-life how much of the sample will decay in that amount of time. Then you can decrease `full_life` by smaller amounts while increasing time likewise to find out when `full_life` finally drops under 1.